# How are variables expanded inside functions in makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use [canned recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html) in my makefile to dynamically define recipes for several subdirectories in my project. However, the variables I have defined are not expanding as I expect them to:

```
define project

$(1)_dir := $(realpath $(2))

.PHONY: $(1)
$(1):
    $(info $(1)_dir = "$($(1)_dir)")

endef

$(eval $(call project,hello_world,./hello-world))
```

I expect the above makefile to print `hello_world_dir = "/path/to/hello-world"` when I run `make hello_world`. However, it prints `hello_world_dir = ""` instead. I don't understand why the nested expansion is not working properly when the variable name is substituted correctly.

Comment: The right question is not so much how as *when*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the nested expansion is not working properly when the variable name is substituted correctly.

It's a timing issue. `$(call)` is just a fancy way to expand a variable.  When you use it to expand variable `project`, all variable and function references within are expanded, too.  At that point, `$(1)` is a reference to a temporary variable provided by `call`, so `$(1)_dir` is expanded as you expect, everywhere it appears in the value of `project`.  The assignment to that variable is properly expanded too, *but it's just text at that point*.  The `$(info ...)` is also expanded at that time, but no variable `hello_world_dir` has yet been defined -- that doesn't happen until the result is `$(eval)`ed.  The output of the `$(info)` properly reflects that at that time, `$(hello_world_dir)` expands to nothing.

First of all, do yourself a favor and dump the embedded `$(info)`.  In addition to *timing* issues with respect to expansion, it also has *content* issues: it expands to nothing, leaving your rule for `hello_world_dir` with a recipe containing only an empty command.  If you want a rule to display text when it runs, then use an `echo` command within.

Second, anything you don't want expanded until the rule's recipe runs needs to be protected from expansion by `$(call)`.  One of the easier ways to do that is to quote `$` symbols by doubling them.

Overall, you might end up with this:

```
define project

$(1)_dir := $(realpath $(2))

.PHONY: $(1)
$(1):
        @echo '$(1)_dir = "$$($(1)_dir)"'

endef

$(eval $(call project,hello_world,./hello-world))
```

Of course, do make sure that `./hello-world` actually designates an existing file or directory.